# Has Chrome browser chosen the wrong icon for 'Clear'?

Tags: usability, gui-design, icons

I know right or wrong is subjective but the developer tools for Chrome (accessible by pressing <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>I</kbd>) has a `Clear` button to delete all values listed. This button is represented with something I normally associate as `no entry` or `disabled` but is this something that can usually be used to represent `Clear`?

[image: Chrome Clear Icon]

The black icon on the right was not obvious to me as the `clear` function, I usually expect an `X` of some sort. Is this icon a new trend or possibly a different cultural meaning?

Comment: I agree--that is a poor choice.

Comment: I agree, I've had momentary pauses before I clicked on it due to this fact

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I agree with you. The fact that at least three of us UX-minded people think it was a bad choice indicates that it probably was one.

The symbol they're using is the ["no" symbol or the "prohibition" symbol](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/No_symbol), which means something a bit different.

Comment: I guess this really comes down to their designer's choice but I haven't seen anyone really disagree. Glad it's not a trend, I can see a lot ensuing confustion if it was :D